# jpeg 32 bit depth not showing on latex

Tags: pdftex, jpeg

My problem is that on a journal portal 300 dpi images are required. When I upload my images of 300 dpi some are uploaded but some are creating problems (when they upload, immediately their dpi converts from 300 to 72)
when I check figures, some figures are 24-bit depth and some are 32-bit depth and it seems that 32-bit depth is uploading correctly and 24-bit depth creating trouble for me.

I have converted 24-bit depth figures to 32-bit depth with an online tool. Then they upload correctly but now my tex file not running pdf although my jpeg images seem good with 32-bit depth?

Comment: Why do you have 32-bit JPEG files in the first place?

Comment: 32 bit jpeg is AFAIK not standardized. Why do you convert your 24 bit pictures to 32 bit? Where would the extra 8 bit information come from?